# Memory keeps rising without getting memory leak notification from leakcanary

Tags: android, memory-management, profiler

I am new to android Profiler and still a noob at memory management. At first, I am having a notifications from LeakCanary so I fix them and successfully removed the leakage so the LeakCanary stops sending me notifications. But when I use the android Profiler I just noticed that the memory usage was rising bit by bit when I open a certain activity and then destroy it using `finish();` method. Below are the sample screenshots of my Profiler when I open and close the `OrdersActivity`.

*Here is the SS of total memory used before opening and closing the `OrdersActivity`*
[image]

*And here is the SS of total memory used after opening and closing the `OrdersActivity`*
[image]

*Also here is the stacktrace of the LeakCanary*
[image]

**I want to know if this occurrence of rising memory is normal? If not, is there a way to stop this? I am willing to show my codes If you need them in order to help me. I just didn't include it because it was too long.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LeakCanary will detect memory leaks, in the sense of objects that remain in memory when the activity is closed.

If you want to understand why memory usage is increasing as an activity is running, you can [track allocations using the profile.](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#record-allocations)

Edit: Also, it's hard to read a screenshot, but it seems to me that was is increasing when you start the activity is **code** (Code: Memory that your app uses for code and resources, such as dex bytecode, optimized or compiled dex code, .so libraries, and fonts.). In that case, that's perfectly normal: starting an activity need to load extra code (the activity itself, which is probably small, and all of required AppCompat if it hasn't been loaded yet). The usual strategy to test against memory leaks is to start and close the activity hundred times, and verify there is no memory increase between the 2nd time and the 100th time.

Comment: When using allocation tracker, look for the allocated vs deallocated numbers. You don't care about total number of objects allocation, but rather the types that are being allocated yet not deallocated when leaving the screen.

Comment: Edit: it seems that the extra memory usage comes from **code**. See added section in my answer.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much! This really helps me a lot!